# text widget returning cursor

Tags: python, tkinter

my problem: in a Tkinter editor I'm writing, there is a condition when I need to reload the file and reopen it returning at the point I'm writing.

My 1st reload attempt is this

```
pos=config.text.index(INSERT)          # memorize where I am
...                                    # do stuff
textopen_and_display(currentfn)        # reopen it
text.mark_set(INSERT,pos)          # go 
text.see(INSERT)                   # there
```

where *text* is my text widget.
The problem is that the .see() method called this way doesnt do what I want: it scrolls down just enough to see the INSERT, and stops. If I am not in the first lines, where the top of file is visible, it doesnt work.

What I need is *the index of the last visible line of the text widget*: how can I find it?
Using .see() on this index should work the way I want

P.S. I am even unable to find the text widget height at runtime, since I defined it as small size (height=5), and PACKed it with  fill=BOTH, expand = 1: asking text.config() for its height it returns the init value of 5

Comment: You can get the actual height at runtime by calling the `winfo_height` method -- that returns the actual height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save your scroll position:

```
x_pos = text.xview()[0]
y_pos = text.yview()[0]
```

To restore the scroll position:

```
text.xview(Tkinter.MOVETO, x_pos)
text.yview(Tkinter.MOVETO, y_pos)
```

Comment: you saved my day, thanks! Caveat: I had to get rid of the "Tkinter." prefixes to the MOVETO arguments, I dont know why...

Comment: @alessandro:  It's the difference between `from Tkinter import *` and `import Tkinter`.